# Does the nationality of an EHIC card need to match the nationality of the passport?

Tags: passports, insurance, eu

When the UK leaves the EU, I am planning to get an Irish passport. I am not eligible to get an Irish EHIC because I am not a resident of Ireland.

So I am wondering, can I use a UK EHIC with an Irish passport as that would save me the cost of a UK passport in the interim

Comment: Why not just use your UK passport with the EHIC (note: EHICs from the UK may or may not be valid after the UK leaves the EU, depending on if the UK negotiations to remain part of the scheme)

Comment: My current UK passport is expired, so if article 50 gets invoked before I renew it might be better to just not renew the UK one (especially if I can use the British EHIC with an Irish passport)

Comment: This is a hypothetical question for the time being. It all depends on what is negotiated.

Comment: @DumbCoder ... The question got silently changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not need to match. I have a UK EHIC card (bound to my insurance as a UK resident) and have a passport of another EU state, that is totally fine and worked well so far. As you can see in the [terms of how to apply](https://www.gov.uk/european-health-insurance-card), you can apply for an EHIC card as a national of the UK, EEA and Switzerland. All what counts is your proof of residency.

*(That concerned the first version of the question):* However, in case the UK leaves the EU completely and without health insurance agreements between the EU and UK being in place, you need (as a UK resident) to take care of your insurance matters yourself (for getting emergency treatments in EU countries).